# non-random selection of training and test datasets for cross validation by python

Tags: python, cross-validation

Suppose that I have 10 separate datasets and I want to build a predictive model. I need to evaluate the model so, I use cross validation. How can I use each dataset as a fold or specific part in CV? For example, how can I use the first 9 datasets as training set and the 10th dataset as test set and then iterate over all datasets? This way, the training and test datasets will not be randomly selected. Is there any python function to perform it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you want using sklearn's KFold provided your data sets are of an equal size and you combine them in one set using pd.concat([df1, df2... df10], ignore_index = True). Shuffling is turned off by default and you can specify the number of folds using n_splits. The default for the latter is 3. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load a data frame
df = pd.read_csv('C:\df.csv')   
print(df)

#                           CROSS VALIDATION

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

# Instantiate KFold
kf= KFold(n_splits = 2)

X = df.iloc[:, :-1]
y = df.iloc[:, -1]

# Show the indices of the train and test sets
print('kf indices:')
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print(train_index, test_index)

    A    B       Name   Surname      Country  Points
0  96  100      Roger   Federer  Switzerland  9600.0
1  80  100     Grigor  Dimitrov     Bulgaria  8000.0
2  72  100    Dominic     Thiem      Austria  7200.0
3  65  100      Pablo     Busta        Spain  6500.0
4  58  100       Stan  Wawrinka  Switzerland  5800.0
5  56  100       Jack      Sock          USA  5600.0
6  44  100      Marin     Cilic      Croatia  4400.0
7  43  100      David    Goffin      Belgium  4300.0
8  25  100  Alexander    Zverev      Germany  2500.0
9  14  100     Rafael     Nadal        Spain  1400.0

kf indices:
[5 6 7 8 9] [0 1 2 3 4]
[0 1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8 9]
```